# Can I move a house a few inches?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Is it possible to move a house a few inches in Animal Crossing?

Answer (score 8):

By a few inches, what do you mean?

You can move your house by talking to Nook in the upgraded resident services building and asking to relocate. This won't be cheap; it'll cost 30,000 bells

For that, I don't think it's worth the few inches that you mean, but if you're desperate, the option is there

Comment: To add: To move a house in AC it costs the same to move your house 1 square away than at the other end of the island.

Answer (score 3):

No.

If you want to relocate a house to a location that overlaps with its current location, you will have to first move it somewhere else, then move it back.